# Does Trine 2 support online co-op between a PS4 and a PC?

Tags: trine-2

Does Trine 2 support online co-op between a PS4 and a PC? I want to play with my friend who only has a PS4 and I only have a PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately cross-platform multiplayer is not supported in any of the Trine games, so playing between PC and PlayStation 4 is not possible. 
-Frozenbyte Support

Comment: Do you have a source for "Frozenbyte Support"? Was it an online FAQ? An e-mail exchange? Something else?

Comment: It was an email exchange: https://imgur.com/a/zOuDqbc